# as.Date returns the day with four digits in R

Tags: r, date, digits, as.date

I am trying to convert a character to date format, but "day" is replaced with 4 digits.

```
> mydate="20/3/20"
> mydate=as.Date(mydate)
> mydate
[1] "0020-03-20"
```

This didn't happen a few days ago, only now as I re-run an old script. I don't know if this has to do with me upgrading recently to R version 3.6.3.

I tried to remove the "00" with gsub, but it turns the date back to character again.

```
> mydate=gsub("00","",mydate)
> class(mydate)
[1] "character"
```

Does anyone know how I can fix that with `mydate` remaining as date, or why this happens?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use the format `as.Date(mydate, "%d/%m/%y")#[1] "2020-03-20"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default format for `Date` class is `"%Y-%m-%d"`  i.e. 4 digit year followed by a dash, followed by two digits, then a dash and two digits.  Any other format, we need to specify the `format` argument in `as.Date`

```
as.Date(mydate, "%d/%m/%y")
#[1] "2020-03-20"
```

---

We need to be very careful with two-digit year as it can lead some strange output.  It is better to have 4 digit year